# Abort long cp operation in Rake

Tags: ruby, windows, copy, rake

I don't know how to abort long `cp` operation when running rake task from `cmd.exe`.

```
cp src, dst
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not work for me in this case (it works in other parts of task).
My current workaround it to close terminal.

Edit:

Example Rakefile

```
First = "first.tmp"
Second = "second.tmp"

file First do
  fills = '1'*1048576 # 1MB write
  puts "Writting #{First}..."
  File.open(First, 'w') do |f|
    2048.times {f.write(fills) } # 2GB total
  end
  puts "Written #{First}."
end

file Second => First do
  puts "Copying #{First} to #{Second}. Test Ctrl+C"
  cp First, Second
  puts "Copied \o/"
end

task :default => [Second]
```

You can stop first run after couple seconds, and another run will just copy first file. Stopping in the middle of copy does not work, interrupt will be performed before next operation (puts).

This is just nonsense example, my real case copies package for one machine to another.

Comment: Please show your rake task.

Comment: You can try `puts Process.pid` before starting the copy then using Taskkill in another terminal to close it.